# .htaccess mod_rewrite playing with variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, variables

I want to have my site urls look like

```
http://example.com/place/info?var=info&morevars=ifneeded
```

Place and info are also variables but they have a fixed name, the ones after would vary. **EDIT** This is the url I am trying to rewrite

```
http://example.com/test.php?place=test&action=info&var=info&morevars=ifneeded
```

This is what I have so far

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ test.php?place=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ test.php?place=$1&action=$2 [NC]
```

I think there a way to do this with {QUERY_STRING} but I can't get it to work just 500 errors or it don't make a differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the [`QSA` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) that automatically appends the original requested query to the new one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ test.php?place=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ test.php?place=$1&action=$2 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, never would have found that in all of the apache docs without you!

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the first /

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/ test2.php?place=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/ test2.php?place=$1&action=$2 [NC]
```

Comment: That doesn't get the the first variables place and info at all, The url its rewriting is http://example.com/test2.php?place=test&action=info&var=info&morevars=ifneeded

Comment: The leading slash is only necessary if you want to use the rule in the server or virtual host configuration. In .htaccess, the contextual per-directory prefix is removed before testing the rules.